# CSS priority over important?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have frontend of a site where the another programmer used inline !important tag somewhere is lot of php files so I cannot track it to change the padding size. I'm left with frontend custom stylesheet to replace that one with !important. But it is already !important. How to change it?

Original HTML & CSS:

```
<ul class="the_champ_facebook_share" style="padding: 7.35px 0 !important;"> .... </ul>
```

I want this one:

```
.the_champ_facebook_share {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: For future reference: As soon you find yourself using `!important` it's clear sign you're most probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Add id in ul and add style to it. Its simple and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` to achieve it.

However, as @Roko C. Buljan's comment, use `!important` is not a good way to do. So you just need to `inline style` without `!important` like below.

**Output**
[image]

```js
$(".the_champ_facebook_share").attr('style', 'padding: 0px');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="the_champ_facebook_share" style="padding: 7.35px 0 !important;"> <li>123</li> </ul>
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but I also think that in this case you wouldn't need `!important` , since this setting *replaces*  the inline setting.

Comment: Yep, I've just updated my answer. please take a look at @Johannes

Comment: @Rob you do realise the code is writen in the answer and that the image you're refering to is a screenshot, an apt display, of the output, which by nature *is graphical*? How would you prefer Phong show that the padding was correctly set if not via the live devtools? Write a function to output the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) (which would deliver text)? Would that really be more readable (they would then need to explain the function after pasting the output text)?

Comment: @Hashbrown Right click on the element. Select 'copy'

Comment: @Rob, I still feel this is apropriate. Grey area at the most, not the type of issue the post you linked is trying to address. Definitely not warranting a bold and capitalised `do not`. Personal opinion: Copying the element might be interpreted, once pasted, as source, and distract from the actual solution they were communicating. It can also look fudged, whereas the screenshot seems more genuine and immediately confers demonstratability. I see your point & agree it can be done that way, I just think it can be done this way too.

Comment: @Hashbrown What I quoted and linked to is the rules from SO.

Comment: Whilst the formatting is that way in the source, it's not immediately obvious you were pasting it sic, verbatim; you can see how it might be interpretated. To try and reiterate what my point was, that rule states `things that are impossible to describe accurately via text` and is subjective. I would say showing the *live view of the DOM in the browser after running the answers code* is really hard to describe and using `Right click on the element. Select 'copy'` does not `describe accurately via text` that concept. If you feel the rules are on your side, just edit the question yourself instead

Answer (score 2):

Your `css` is invalid use this one:

```css
.the_champ_facebook_share {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

That will not solve the problem because the inline style is more important. You will definitively need to remove it from the `html`.

As mentionned by [@Phong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9071943/phong) you will be able to update the style dynamically using `javascript`. That's definitively not a good practice -> really overkill. Good thing to do would be to search in all your files (very simple with a basic IDE) the word `the_champ_facebook_share` then remove this inline style.

Comment: thanks, i changed it. but still the non zero padding has prioirity and my is not displyaing

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have written it wrong, this is how CSS syntax is written:

[image: CSS syntax]

Therefore,

```css
.the_champ_facebook_share {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: So it's a minor typo and we can close the question as one?

Answer (score -1):

Add id in this ul and then put style into it. Its can override your !important property because id has greater priority then class.

```css
#new_facebook_champ{
padding: 7.35px 0 !important;
}
.the_champ_facebook_share{
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="the_champ_facebook_share" id="new_facebook_champ"> .... </ul>
```

Comment: This is incorrect since the `ul` use inline styles with `style=""`. Add an `id` to it with new styles will not have a high-priority.